# There is a problem with reindexing process

Tags: reindex

I reindexed everything, except I can't get this last point to reindex, the
`"Catalog URL Rewrites  Index product and categories URL rewrites "`.

In exception.log I get this error message when I try to reindex it:

```
Exception message: SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1139 Got error 'this version of PCRE is compiled without UTF support at offset 0' from regexp, query was: SELECT MAX(CAST(SUBSTRING(`request_path`, 33, LENGTH(`request_path`) - 32 - 5) AS SIGNED)) FROM `core_url_rewrite` WHERE (store_id = :store_id) AND (request_path LIKE :request_path) AND (request_path REGEXP '^french\\-cuff\\-cotton\\-twill\\-oxford\\-[0-9]*\\.html$')
```

What is the cause of this?

If I delete some of the (sample data) products mentioned in the error stack trace, I can reindex but I don't want to delete products from the database.

Comment: Have a look there: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10037336/pcre-is-compiled-without-utf-support

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try to delete all the data from core_url_rewrite table manually hope this helps

Comment: Be carefull of this. You will also delete any custom created rewrites. Best to exclude them.

Comment: This might've helped, but I already resolved the problem by deleting some of the products. If my problem re-emerges, I will definitely try that.